# "JSON Web Authentication (JWT)" module support for 3rd party JTW issuer

Tags: authentication-authorization

Does Drupal "JSON Web Authentication (JWT)" module support authenticating JWTs generated by a 3rd party JWT Issuer (rather than by the internal module's Issuer)?